# SVG element is not respecting CSS commands, it always sits in the middle of the screen and I don't know why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have put together a web page with multiple SVG elements on it, even though the x,y coordinates are set to 0,0 and the CSS used instructs it to position on the left side of the page, the SVG just sits in the middle.

This is a link to the issue replicated in jsFiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/wf806vvL/
```

Here is the HTML:

```css
svg {
  float:left;
  content-align: left;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="circleGroup" width="100%" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 700 1000">
  <circle id="circle" class="circle" cx="100" cy="125" r="20" fill="#1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

I have tried every different CSS styling that relates to position that I could try, as well as holding the SVG in a div and applying positioning to that, none of this works.

My limited knowledge of CSS and HTML means I have run out of things to try, and since its probably something obvious that I'm missing I thought i'd post it here.

Anyone know why this would be?

Comment: start with making a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of the issue

Comment: @maioman Here is the issue in jsFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/wf806vvL/

Comment: @maioman no need for a fiddle, there's a running script inside the editor.

Comment: If an answer solves your issue, please accept an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle isn't centered in the `viewbox`.

With `viewBox="0 0 700 1000"` the center co-ordinates of your circle would be `cx="350" cy="500"`

```css
svg {
  width: 25%;
  /* for demo */
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="circleGroup" viewBox="0 0 700 1000">

  <circle id="circle" class="circle" cx="350" cy="500" r="20" fill="#1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although my problem is getting the SVG to align on the left, not the centre of the page. 
I have loads of blank space on the left of my main content container, and I can't get the SVG to move into the space in order to free up the right side of the page.

Comment: The SVG **is** aligned left....it's just 100% wide ...see - https://jsfiddle.net/wf806vvL/1/

Comment: I thought that if the 0,0 on the SVG canvas was the top left corner then the X value of the circle being 100 would bring is closer into the left side?
The Y value in this case is greater than the X value, yet the circle is closer to the top of the SVG than to the left, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It is closer to the left side...but the SVG canvas (`viewbox`) is 700 wide by 1000 tall. If you want the circle centered in a 700 x 1000 canvas...the center has to be at 350 / 500.

Comment: When I set it up on my web page it is more than halfway over the screen, when I want it to be 100px from the left edge of the container, i want to free up the centre, and right of the page for other elements.

Comment: Then you really need to demo **that** issue...your code at the moment you only show the SVG.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `height="100vh"` to `100%`, and setting `cx` to 21 and `cy` to 100 places the circle where you want it (as far as I understood):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="circleGroup" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 700 1000">
  <circle id="circle" class="circle" cx="100" cy="21" r="20" fill="#1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```